# Two return statements in SQLite helper class not permitted

Tags: android, sqlite, return, android-sqlite

To understand my question we need to explain the project design. We have a simple MVP concept with a DB that has 3 columns id name cost(int) The DBHelper and Model Classes are used and a ListActivity that is backed by a RecyclerAdapter as well as a DetailsActivity that displays all the elements from the DB when an item in the ListActivity is selected. The launch activity MainActivity will permit the user to run a number of queries standard fair show all the data in the ArrayList that is populated in the DBHelper after a call from the ListActivity Here is the important part the DBHelper has this statement to send the dbList back to ListActivity "return modelList" So we decided to create a query that SUMS the values in the cost column and RETURN the sum to the MainActivity. DBHelper is quite unhappy with TWO RETURN statements. Because the call to the DBHelper is made from the ListActivity we tried to bypass this by making a direct call from MainActivity NO Way DBHelper says one RETURN statement. My question is how to return the sum value from DBHelper? The query works and we will post the code that is called from Main below.

```
    public sumALL(){
    Cursor cursorA =null;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM " + TABLE_INFO;
    cursorA = db.rawQuery(q,null);
    if(cursorA.moveToFirst()){

        totalPrice = cursorA.getInt(0);
    }

    cursorA.close();
    db.close();
    return totalPrice;
```

Comment: **Every method** shall have **one only return** statement!

Comment: @ModularSynth Yes I agree with that but the second method is just that one of two. We are not involving the method that populates the dbList We think because the Cost column is in the model Class that is why DBHelper is complaining

Comment: `the second method` ... **which one**? I only see **one** method.

Comment: How can you return a value (in this case - totalPrice) from **void** method?

Comment: Moreover, all the statements **after** the `return()` statement aren't executed. `return()` ends the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one who looks at the first two answers YES they work and both do not address the question, Nor did the commentators and yours truly look closely at the construction of the method in the DBHelper Class this public sumALL(){
is so wrong it should be public int sumALL(){ so making a call from the MainActivity code will be posted and the properly constructed sumALL method for the DBHelper will be posted

Call code from MainActivity

```
        helper = new DBHelper(this);
        helper.summALL();
        etLineTwo.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // Set your desired format here.
        String dollarSIGN = df.format(totalPrice/100.0);
        etLineTwo.setText(String.valueOf("of Gas   $"+dollarSIGN));
```

Code for DBHelper method with the return

```
    public int summALL(){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM " + TABLE_INFO;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        totalPrice = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return totalPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK this is not easy nor is it simple I will try to explain the steps needed. I have a simple MVP design for testing you might keep one around for testing new ideas. First you need to add this code in the Activity that does the calling to the DBHelper Class NO INTENT to make the trip to the DBHelper

Here is the code in the MainActivity that calls the method in DBHelper

```
static Context contextX;

contextX = this.getBaseContext();

public void onSUM(View view){
Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Sum the Cost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG 
 ).show();
helper = new DBHelper(this);
helper.sumALL();
```

}

Now the code in DBHelper with the Intent that bundles the totalPrice

```
    public void sumALL(){
    Cursor cursorA =null;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM " + TABLE_INFO;
    cursorA = db.rawQuery(q,null);
    if(cursorA.moveToFirst()){

        totalPrice = cursorA.getInt(0);
    }

    cursorA.close();
    db.close();
    //return totalPrice;

    Bundle extrasB = new Bundle();
    extrasB.putInt("BACK",totalPrice);
    contextX = MainActivity.contextX;
    Intent intentB = new Intent(contextX,ShowTotalActivity.class);

    intentB.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    // required to use intent in non Activity Class
    intentB.putExtras(extrasB);
    contextX.startActivity(intentB);

}
```

Because the MainActivity is the launcher you will have issues retrieving the bundle in that activity So we created a new Activity as you can see in the Intent here is the retrieval of the bundle code

```
    Context contextX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_total);
    etTotal =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTotal);
    btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

    Intent intentB = getIntent();
    Bundle extrasB = intentB.getExtras();
    int costB = extrasB.getInt("BACK");

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // Set your desired format 
    String dollarSIGN = df.format(costB/100.0);
    etTotal.setText(String.valueOf("Total of Gas   $"+dollarSIGN));
```

Some may ask why the odd name contextX that is because DBHelper has a context declaration just trying to avoid conflict We also had to declare totalPrice as
public static Integer totalPrice in MainActivity and import it to DBHelper

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by Grendel will work it requires more code and seems difficult because of the inherit design We decided to not use the DBHelper to run the query but to execute the query within the MainActivity to deal with the issue of only one return in the DBHelper the code used in the MainActivity is posted below This design requires importing the DBHelper back to the MainActivity

```
import static com.<package_name>.DBHelper.TABLE_INFO;
```

private DBHelper helper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public void onSUM(View view){
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Sum the Cost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

```
Cursor cursor =null;
helper = new DBHelper(this);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
String q = "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM " + TABLE_INFO;
cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

    totalPrice = cursor.getInt(0);
}

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String dollarSIGN = df.format(totalPrice/100.0);
etTotoal.setText(String.valueOf("Total of Gas   $"+dollarSIGN));

cursor.close();
db.close();
```

}

Comment: Looks great and yes less code not sure if this is good practice  It would be nice if someone would comment about the two returns in DBHelper Class Good part is Android always has two ways to do somethng